# Perform action on WPMU blog deletion

Tags: multisite, hooks, actions

Hi guys :) I know there is the `wpmu_new_blog` action hook which enables us to perform an action when a new WPMU blog is created. Is there something similar to this which enables us to perform an action when a WPMU blog is deleted? Something which looks like this:

`add_action('blog_deletion_hook', 'function_to_perform')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, inside [`/wp-admin/includes/ms.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/ms.php#L65) there is the action hook `delete_blog`.

This test prevents a blog deletion:

```
add_action( 'delete_blog', 'prevent_blog_delete_wpse_82961', 10, 2 );

/**
* @param int $blog_id Blog ID
* @param bool $drop True if blog's table should be dropped. Default is false.
*/
function prevent_blog_delete_wpse_82961( $blog_id, $drop ) 
{
    wp_die( 'aborting delete_blog' );
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Although I ran into the problem that the action I wanted to perform on deletion didn't work with WPMU. I solved this by 'Network Enabling' the plugin. :)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress use since version 5.1 a new hook.

`do_action( 'wp_delete_site', $old_site );`

The var `$old_site` is the deleted site object.

If you need a hook before the blog will delete, use the hook below.

```
 * Fires before a site should be deleted from the database.
 *
 * Plugins should amend the `$errors` object via its `WP_Error::add()` method. If any errors
 * are present, the site will not be deleted.
 *
 * @since 5.1.0
 *
 * @param WP_Error $errors   Error object to add validation errors to.
 * @param WP_Site  $old_site The site object to be deleted.
 */
do_action( 'wp_validate_site_deletion', $errors, $old_site );
```

You should use a hook from this two options because the hook `delete_blog` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this is now deprecated. I haven't found a substitute yet, unfortunately :(
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_blog/