# WPMU Hook for archive or deactivate blog?

Tags: multisite, hooks

I am trying to automatically clear the blog's cache when it is Archived (or Deactivated is fine) in a Multisite install. This is useful for anyone using a caching program like WP Super Cache as an archived or deactivated the blog will still show until the cache is cleared.

I have tried:

```
add_action( 'archive_blog', 'wp_clear_cache_custom' );
add_action( 'unarchive_blog', 'wp_clear_cache_custom');
```

And:

```
add_action( 'archive_blog', 'wp_clear_cache_custom_archive', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'unarchive_blog', 'wp_clear_cache_custom_archive', 10, 1 );
```

With the function:

```
function wp_clear_cache_custom() {
        global $wpdb;
        wp_cache_clear_cache( $wpdb->blogid );
}
```

This same setup works fine for clearing the cache when a theme is changed, etc. but not for blog status changes.

Any help is much appreciated.

This page seemed to be close but no dice:
[Perform action on WPMU blog deletion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82961/perform-action-on-wpmu-blog-deletion)

Answer (score 0):

According to [wpseek.com](http://wpseek.com), there exist hooks for [`unarchive_blog`](http://wpseek.com/hook/unarchive_blog/), [`archive_blog`](http://wpseek.com/hook/archive_blog/), and [`deactivate_blog`](http://wpseek.com/hook/deactivate_blog/).  You can examine them in the source on WordPress's Trac site:

- [`archive_blog`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php#L359)
- [`unarchive_blog`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php#L368)
- [`deactivate_blog`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/network/sites.php#L158)

All of them use the `$blog_id` parameter.  Try changing your function to reflect that:

```
add_action( 'archive_blog', 'wp_clear_cache_custom' );
function wp_clear_cache_custom( $blog_id ) {
    wp_cache_clear_cache( $blog_id );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Pat. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I tried that too and it did not clear the cache like the below does:
`add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'wp_clear_cache_custom' );
function wp_clear_cache_custom() {
        global $wpdb;
        wp_cache_clear_cache( $wpdb->blogid );
}`