# Is there a hook or a function for multisite blog deactivate or delete?

Tags: multisite

Is there a way to detect if a blog was deleted, deactivated or archived within a Multisite installation ?

Something that will be the opposite of `wpmu_new_blog`

I've search google, wasn't much help.

Searched here found: [WPMU Hook for archive or deactivate blog?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/wpmu-hook-for-archive-or-deactivate-blog)

This post looks relevant however they did not cover deletion nor was it confirmed working by the 'op'.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the top answer of [the question you found](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128513/28916) you can read that the user found the hook `wpmu_deactivate_blog` on [wpseek.com](http://wpseek.com/).

Searching for `delete_blog` got me here: [delete_blog](http://wpseek.com/hook/delete_blog/). I think `delete_blog` is the hook you're looking for. Try it and maybe you can confirm it yourself.

**From the WP3.0 source:**

`delete_blog` is an Action hook that's fired in the `wpmu_delete_blog` function.

```
function wpmu_delete_blog( $blog_id, $drop = false ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $switch = false;
    if ( get_current_blog_id() != $blog_id ) {
        $switch = true;
        switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    }

    $blog = get_blog_details( $blog_id );
    /**
     * Fires before a blog is deleted.
     *
     * @since MU
     *
     * @param int  $blog_id The blog ID.
     * @param bool $drop    True if blog's table should be dropped. Default is false.
     */
    do_action( 'delete_blog', $blog_id, $drop );
```

By the looks of it, the function switches to the right blog before firing the `delete_blog` action hook.

Comment: Alright seems all 3 works `delete_blog, archive_blog, deactivate_blog` Thanks